# IDataContractSurrogate, NHibernate and nulling proxy objects

Tags: c#, wcf, nhibernate

I'm faced with yet another "mystery" when it comes to serialization and deserialization in WCF. Let me walk you through the details;

- We have a presisted object (NHibernate) which we are returning from a
  WCF service (hosted by TCP).
- We have a DataContractSurrogate which
  checks if properties/collections are NHibernate proxies and if so do
  one of the following things:

  - Return the object if the proxy is initialized (and the correct type for serialization)
  - Return NULL if the proxy is not initialized

So far so good, the DataContractSurrogate does it's job, serializes and sends the message neatly to the client where i get the following error when Deserializing:

> Unable to cast object of type 'System.Object' to type 'XXXXXXXXXX'

At this point why the hell is it casting a NULL valua? Does this mean i can't make the property NULL what is this madness?

So i decided to check if there is any difference in the way my DataContractSurrogate handles NULL values instead of our proxy. I basically just set the previously mentioned property to NULL manually instead of letting the DataContractSurrogate do this for me.

Magically, this works... Which really makes my jaw drop, so i decide to step through the different methods of the DataContractSurrogate to see what's happening and here is what i noticed.

When i manually NULL the property for some reason (most likely because some layer further to the top tells it not to) GetObjectToSerialize is never called. Obviously when i do not manually set the property to NULL the method is called and i return a NULL instead of the proxy/initialized object.

Here are the two methods from my DataContractSurrogate incase those are interesting to anyone:

```
public Type GetDataContractType(Type type)
{
    // Serialize proxies as the base type
    if (typeof(INHibernateProxy).IsAssignableFrom(type))
    {
       type = type.GetType().BaseType;
    }

    // Serialize persistent collections as the collection interface type
    if (typeof(IPersistentCollection).IsAssignableFrom(type))
    {
        foreach (Type collInterface in type.GetInterfaces())
        {
            if (collInterface.IsGenericType)
            {
                type = collInterface;
                break;
            }
            else if (!collInterface.Equals(typeof(IPersistentCollection)))
            {
                type = collInterface;
            }
         }
     }

     return type;
 }

 public object GetObjectToSerialize(object obj, Type targetType)
 {
    // Serialize proxies as the base type
    if (obj is INHibernateProxy)
    {
        ILazyInitializer init = ((INHibernateProxy)obj).HibernateLazyInitializer;
        if (init.IsUninitialized)
        {
           obj = null;
        }
        else
        {
           obj = init.GetImplementation();    
        }
     }

     // Serialize persistent collections as the collection interface type
     if (obj is IPersistentCollection)
     {
         //return 
         if (!((IPersistentCollection)obj).WasInitialized)
         {
             Type type = typeof(Collection<>).MakeGenericType(obj.GetType().GetGenericArguments());
             obj = Activator.CreateInstance(type);
         }
      }

      return obj;
  }
```

What i'm wondering is how i can get this to work, i want to be able to mindlessly return my presisted objects (yes, DTO's would solve this but i do not want to go down that road, it's just more work to maintain then getting this to function IMO).

Anyone have any ideas on how to get this working (On the client side the GetObjectToSerialize is not called, the Type is requested and then BAM it blows up)?

Edit:

This is the message after serialized:

```
<OnReceiveCall xmlns="http://tempuri.org/">
<call xmlns:b="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/TelephoneExchange.Entities" xmlns:i="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
<b:Begin>2012-10-03T14:57:20</b:Begin>
**<b:CallingTelephone i:type="c:anyType" xmlns:c="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"></b:CallingTelephone>**
<b:End i:nil="true"></b:End>
<b:HasRecording>false</b:HasRecording>
<b:ID>149688</b:ID>
<b:Inputs></b:Inputs>
<b:LeftInQueue>false</b:LeftInQueue>
<b:RecipientTelephone>
<b:IsInternal>true</b:IsInternal>
<b:Name>604</b:Name>
<b:Number>604</b:Number>
</b:RecipientTelephone>
<b:TransUniqueID i:nil="true"></b:TransUniqueID>
</call>
</OnReceiveCall>
```

Bit between ** and  ** is the property of interest.

When i manually null the property the XML looks like this:

```
<OnReceiveCall xmlns="http://tempuri.org/">
<call xmlns:d4p1="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/TelephoneExchange.Entities" xmlns:i="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
<d4p1:Begin>2012-10-03T15:04:18</d4p1:Begin>
**<d4p1:CallingTelephone i:nil="true"></d4p1:CallingTelephone>**
<d4p1:End i:nil="true"></d4p1:End>
<d4p1:HasRecording>false</d4p1:HasRecording>
<d4p1:ID>149721</d4p1:ID>
<d4p1:Inputs></d4p1:Inputs>
<d4p1:LeftInQueue>false</d4p1:LeftInQueue>
<d4p1:RecipientTelephone>
<d4p1:IsInternal>true</d4p1:IsInternal>
<d4p1:Name>604</d4p1:Name>
<d4p1:Number>604</d4p1:Number>
</d4p1:RecipientTelephone>
<d4p1:TransUniqueID i:nil="true"></d4p1:TransUniqueID>
</call>
</OnReceiveCall>
```

Note the difference.... Now the question is... how the hell do i make this work :-)

Answer (score 0):

The problem is here:

```
// Serialize proxies as the base type 
if (typeof(INHibernateProxy).IsAssignableFrom(type)) 
{ 
   type = type.GetType().BaseType; 
}
```

<s>This is a common mistake.  `type` is itself an object that represents the type of your (possibly proxy) object; the type of `type` is `System.Type`.  Therefore, `type.GetType()` returns `typeof(System.Type)` and the base type of that is `object`.  Your code therefore creates an instance of `object` rather than an instance of the proxy's base type.</s>

Assuming you really do want to serialize proxies as the base type, you need this:

```
// Serialize proxies as the base type 
if (typeof(INHibernateProxy).IsAssignableFrom(type)) 
{ 
   type = type.BaseType; 
}
```

EDIT:

Null is probably a red herring here.

First, it's allowed to cast null to any reference type; the type of null is not `System.Object`, so casting null would not result in an exception about casting System.Object to another type.

Second, if an object is null, then `obj is SomeType` evaluates to `false`.  GetObjectToSerialize will therefore return null if its first argument is null.  You don't show the call site for GetDataContractType, so it's hard to see how a null property value would affect it.

Edit 2:

Of course, the above is incorrect, because `type.GetType()` returns `typeof(System.RuntimeType), not`typeof(System.Type)`.

Here's the correct analysis:

This is a common mistake.  `type` is itself an object that represents the type of your (possibly proxy) object; the static type of `type` is `System.Type`; the runtime type is most likely `System.RuntimeType`.  Therefore, `type.GetType()` returns `typeof(System.RuntimeType)` and the base type of that is `System.Reflection.TypeInfo`.  Your code therefore serializes a null `System.Reflection.TypeInfo` reference rather than an instance of the proxy's base type.

Try adding this line immediately before the return statement at the end of GetDataContractType to see what happens:

```
if (typeof(System.Type).IsAssignableFrom(type))
    throw new Exception("oops");
```

Comment: I'm afraid there is nothing wrong with type.GetType().BaseType. The GetDataContractType always returns the correct types. (Never System.Object). Tried your suggestion aswell and it gave the exact same result as the code already present, eitherway weither or not this part is correct or not does not seem related to the problem because the value returned from the method is correct (not System.Object, but the correct reference type)

Comment: The problem also does not seem to be within the serialization (the solution might be found there, but no expection are thrown while serializing) The exceptions are thrown on the Client while DEserializing.

Comment: Basically the client is recieving a System.Object (which should be a NULL value) which it's trying to serialize as Type 'XXXXXXX' which returns the cast exception. Maybe it would be nice to get the actual XML send over the line but i am not sure how i would get the XML send by the service/recieved by the client.

Comment: @F.B.tenKate I suppose you've done *some* sort of test to show that GetDataContractType never returns System.Object -- what was that test?

Comment: @F.B.tenKate there *is* something wrong with type.GetType().BaseType, but my initial analysis was incorrect.  Please see Edit 2 for more detail.

Comment: I simply ran the code in debug mode, and walked through the DataContractSurugate. GetDataContractType doesn't return any instance, simply a System.Type as you stated. You might very well be correct that that section of code is not correct however, it does not even enter the if statement and always returns the correct type.

Comment: If you notice my edits the problem is in the XML that the serialization produces, because i'm making the GetObjectToSerialize method return null instead of the type which it would normally have (Telephone in this case) the XML serialized changes from how the XML would look if i had made the property null OUTSIDE of the DataContractSurogate.

Comment: @F.B.tenKate okay, let's take a step back.  Is GetDataContractType ever called with `typeof(Telephone)` as its argument?  If so, what does it return in that case?  I assume the value of CallingTelephone property is null, so there should be a call to GetObjectToSerialize that corresponds to this property, where `obj` is null.  What is the value of the `targetType` parameter for that call?

Comment: the targetType is of the type "Telephone" as expected. The problem is the difference in XML generated between the two "test cases". The one where I NULL the property manually (so NOT in the DataContractSurogate) i:nul="true" is used while when it's beeing set to NULL inside the GetObjectToSerialize the XML looks different. At serialization this posses no problem (hence the resulting XML) but on the client at Deserialization the exception which is bothering me is thrown.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/17556/discussion-between-phoog-and-f-b-ten-kate)